# Missing elements for a Google Cloud Video Annotation request

Tags: google-api, video-intelligence-api

I am trying to run annotation on a video using the Google Cloud Video Intelligence API. Annotation requests with just one feature request (i.e., one of "LABEL_DETECTION", "SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION" or "EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION"), things work fine. However, when I request an annotation with two or more features at the same time, the response does not always return all the request feature fields. For example, here is a request I ran recently using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/videointelligence/v1/videointelligence.videos.annotate?fields=done%252Cerror%252Cmetadata%252Cname%252Cresponse&_h=3&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522features%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%2522EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION%2522%252C%2522LABEL_DETECTION%2522%252C%2522SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION%2522%250A%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%2522inputUri%2522%253A%20%2522gs%253A%252F%252Fgccl_dd_01%252FVideo1%2522%250A%257D&):

```
{
 "features": [
   "EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION",
   "LABEL_DETECTION",
   "SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION"
 ],
 "inputUri": "gs://gccl_dd_01/Video1"
}
```

The operation Id I got back is this: "us-east1.11264560501473964275". When I run a GET with this Id, I have the following response:

```
200

{
 "name": "us-east1.11264560501473964275",
 "metadata": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.videointelligence.v1.AnnotateVideoProgress",
  "annotationProgress": [
   {
    "inputUri": "/gccl_dd_01/Video1",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2018-08-06T17:13:58.129978Z",
    "updateTime": "2018-08-06T17:18:01.274877Z"
   },
   {
    "inputUri": "/gccl_dd_01/Video1",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2018-08-06T17:13:58.129978Z",
    "updateTime": "2018-08-06T17:14:39.074505Z"
   },
   {
    "inputUri": "/gccl_dd_01/Video1",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2018-08-06T17:13:58.129978Z",
    "updateTime": "2018-08-06T17:16:23.230536Z"
   }
  ]
 },
 "done": true,
 "response": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.videointelligence.v1.AnnotateVideoResponse",
  "annotationResults": [
   {
    "inputUri": "/gccl_dd_01/Video1",
    "segmentLabelAnnotations": [
     ...
    ],
    "shotLabelAnnotations": [
     ...
    ],
    "shotAnnotations": [
     ...
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

The done parameter for the response is set to true, but it does not have any field containing the annotations for Explicit Content.

This issue seems to be occurring at random to my novice eyes. The APIs will return a response with all parameters on some occasions and be missing one on others. I am wondering if there is anything I am missing here or something on my end that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests using just `LABEL_DETECTION`, just `EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION` and using the three of them.

As I am not using videos with explicit content, I don't see any specific field when adding just `EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION`:

```
{
  "name": "europe-west1.462458490043912485",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.videointelligence.v1.AnnotateVideoProgress",
    "annotationProgress": [
      {   
        "inputUri": "/cloud-ml-sandbox/video/chicago.mp4",
        "startTime": "2018-08-07T14:18:40.086713Z",
        "updateTime": "2018-08-07T14:18:40.230351Z"
      }   
    ]   
  }
}
```

Can you share a specific video sample, the `request.json` used and two different outputs, please?